# Cannot get SQL client to work in binary powershell module

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, sqlclient

What I did

I installed powershell 7 (x64 windows)
Create a new c# .net core class library (VS2019 .net core 3.1)
Added nuget for

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.0.1
Powershellstandard.library 5.1.0
microsoft.sqlserver.dacfx
```

created a class derived from PSCmdlet and added this:

```
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection($"Server={Server};Trusted_Connection=True;");
sqlConnection.Open();
```

Depending on if I add "CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies" is true

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <RootNamespace>VaultTech.Powershell</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>VaultTech.Powershell</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to the project file I get either a "platform not supported error" from sqldataclient or I get an "assembly not found" for sqldataclient.

For some reason CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies also makes my breakpoints work in the powershell module....

Looking on the net I see some similar error reports but nothing in them provides a solution to me. Mostly talking about nuget not recognizing the platform and thus not adding the correct assemblies or such. Using sql in a cmdlet should not be a hard thing to do.

What am I missing? Do I have the wrong powershell library or something????

**UPDATE 1**

After many combinations of packages I discovered that using system.data.sqlclient 4.6.1 works. And only that version seems to be acceptable by powershell. However this only solves part of my problem. The other half is that i want de use dacservices from microsoft.sqlserver.dacfx. This package itself depends on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.0 and that still fails with a "platform not supported"

**UPDATE 2**

Switching to a .net framework library and the old windows only powershell versions (5 and lower) makes everything work properly. Packages installed.

```
Powershellstandard.library 5.1.0
microsoft.sqlserver.dacfx
```

Everything works fine then. But I want to target the newer cross platform version 7 and that one is .net core based.

**CODE**

People keep asking about code, but this really is not a code problem but a dependency problem or such. But just to entertain the code notion:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PowerShell
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "Vault")]
    [OutputType(typeof(Boolean))]
    public class AddVaultCmdlet : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true,
            HelpMessage = "Server instance to create the vault on")]
        public string Server { get; set; }

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true,
            HelpMessage = "Name of the vault database")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        private SqlConnection sqlConnection;

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            base.BeginProcessing();
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection($"Server={Server};Trusted_Connection=True;");
            sqlConnection.Open();
            
            WriteVerbose("Begin!");
        }


        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = $"Server={Server};Trusted_Connection=True;";

               
                // Roll out the dacpac for the vault
                DacServices dacpacService = new DacServices(connectionString);
                dacpacService.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler<DacProgressEventArgs>((s, e) =>
                            WriteProgress(new ProgressRecord(1, "Deploy dacpac", e.Message)));
                dacpacService.Message += new EventHandler<DacMessageEventArgs>((s, e) =>
                                WriteInformation(new InformationRecord(e.Message.Message, "Deploy dacpac")));


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteError(new ErrorRecord(ex, "1", ErrorCategory.NotSpecified, ""));
                WriteObject(false);
            }
            finally
            {
                WriteObject(true);
            }

        }

        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            base.EndProcessing();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }

    }
   
}
```

**Project file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <AssemblyName>PowerShell</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>PowerShell</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx" Version="150.4897.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>



  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Resource.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resource.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resource.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resource.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: See following : https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1-known-issues.md

Comment: @jdweng. That unfortunately does not help me. An downgrade did solve it a little but not completely. I have updated the question. Seems to be somthing in the way powershell loads its cmdlets that forces specific versions of assemblies.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Powershell or `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. You haven't posted your code or your project file, so one can only guess. `Depending on if I add true to the project file` what does that mean? The errors say that either the *wrong* libraries were copied for the target platform (eg x64 was deployed on a x86 system) or that the libraries are missing completely

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the "true" was a little typo, the stackoverflow editor was hiding the xml. I adjusted it. I also added a second update and a code example, though this is in mu opinion a dependy problem in the project or in powershell and the way it loads it commandlets.